# Get Posts from Facebook Page PHP

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I've done a lot of searching on the world wide web for this but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I want to be able to get all of the posts in order of upload from a specific Facebook page without needing a user to login. I would want all the data coming in a JSON format and using either PHP or if needed Javascript.

I know I don't have any code but I've spent many hours trying to get the answer behind this and asking here is my last resort really. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is in the official Facebook docs, including example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#read

It´s actually the first entry when you search for "get facebook page posts" with Google ;)

Without user login, you can only get posts of a Page if it´s not restricted by age or location. You can use an App Access Token for that.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/